# gcc command crashes at linking (ld) operation

Tags: linux, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS system with kernel version 3.14. And GCC version is gcc-4.6

```
# uname -a
Linux SC-TXT-node1 3.14.18-custom #1 SMP Fri Sep 12 14:03:23 PDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# gcc --version
gcc-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

While doing compilation of any C files, I am facing segmentation fault.

```
# gcc test.c
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]
```

I found that running the command - "ld" also throws segmentation fault.

The "dmesg" gives the following error, but I am not able to get what does it mean

```
#dmesg
[83719.292987] ld.bfd.real[60413]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000000001 sp 00007fff7bede118 error 14 in ld.bfd.real[7f6f156c2000+3000]
[83719.293192] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport 60413 11 0 pipe failed
```

Strace for ld gives following output

```
# strace ld -v
....
readlink("/usr/bin/ld.bfd", "hardened-ld", 4095) = 11
stat("/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=30038, ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7ae6c06150}, {SIG_IGN,    [FPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f7ae6c06150}, 8) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real", ["/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real", "-v"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

From the outer part seems the ld is refering to some wrong address, but I don't know what is causing this issue.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: I suspect a bad GCC installation, maybe try reinstalling it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar. Can you please let me know the steps to re-install it?

Comment: There are a number of answers to that on askubuntu.com. They show up as the top hits when I google "how to install gcc on ubuntu"

Comment: Thanks Barmar.. I did it and its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC files seems to be corrupted. Reinstalling GCC helped to correct this issue.